# Product of distinct values before a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with schema:

```
date     | item_id | factor
----------------------
20180710 | 1  | 0.1
20180711 | 1  | 0.1
20180712 | 1  | 2
20180713 | 1  | 2
20180714 | 1  | 2
20180710 | 2  | 0.1
20180711 | 2  | 0.1
20180712 | 2  | 5
20180713 | 2  | 5
20180714 | 2  | 10
```

The factor for each item_id can change on any date. On each date, I need to calculate the product of all the distinct factors for each item_id up to that date (inclusive), so the final output for the above table should be:

```
date     | id | cumulative_factor
20180710 | 1  | 0.1
20180711 | 1  | 0.1
20180712 | 1  | 0.2
20180713 | 1  | 0.2
20180714 | 1  | 0.2
20180710 | 2  | 0.1
20180711 | 2  | 0.1
20180712 | 2  | 0.5
20180713 | 2  | 0.5
20180714 | 2  | 5
```

Logic:

On 20180711, for id=1, the distinct factors is 0.1 only, so the cumulative factor is 0.1.

On 20180714, for id=1, the distinct factors are 0.1 and 2, so the cumulative factor is 0.1*2 = 0.2.

On 20180714, for id=2, the distinct factors are 0.1, 5 and 10, so the cumulative factor is 0.1*5*10 = 5.

I've tried

```
select a.id, a.date, b.cum_factor   
from factor_table a
left join (
    select id, date, ISNULL(EXP(SUM(distinct log_factor)),1) as cum_factor 
    from factor_table
    where date < a.date  
    ) b
    on a.id=b.id and a.date = b.date
```

but I get the error

> a.date not found

Comment: Could you explain what's your expect result logic?

Comment: please also post your table schema

Comment: A is not a table.

Comment: I've edited the question with the logic. I'm not sure what else I can do to provide the schema. The table contains three colums: date, id, and factor.

Comment: i don't understand how you can return DISTINCT rows with IDs, then they are just the rows you've got

Comment: Uh....  If a.date exists and b.date exists your 'select date' is going to throw an error for being ambiguous.

Comment: `The table contains three colums: date, id, and factor`. So where is `datadate` comes from ?

Comment: @Squirrel my bad, that was meant to be date. I forgot to edit that when I was modifying my actual query to suit this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a product aggregate function in SQL Server.

However, you can emulate it with `EXP ( SUM ( LAG ( value ) ) )`

please refer to in-line query for the comments

```
; with 
cte as
(
    -- this cte set the factor to 1 if it is same as previous row
    -- as you wanted `product of distinct`
    select  *, 
            factor2 = CASE WHEN LAG(factor) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                                      ORDER BY [date]) IS NULL
                           OR   LAG(factor) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                                      ORDER BY [date]) <> factor                
                           THEN factor
                           ELSE 1
                           END
    from    factor_table
),
cte2 as
(
    -- this cte peform SUM( LOG ( factor ) ) only. except EXP()
    select  *, factor3 = SUM(LOG(factor2)) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                                     ORDER BY [date])
    from    cte
)
-- EXP() is not a window function, so it has to do it in separately in another level
select  *, EXP(factor3) as cumulative_factor
from    cte2
```

Note : LAG() required SQL Server 2012 or later

Answer (score 1):

Something seems wrong with multiplying *distinct* factors.  You can pretty easily express this using window functions:

```
select f.id, f.date, f.cum_factor  
       exp(sum(distinct log(log_factor) over (partition by f.id order by f.date)))  
from factor_table f;
```

To get around the limitation on `distinct`:

```
select f.id, f.date, f.cum_factor  
       exp(sum(log(case when seqnum = 1 then log_factor end) over (partition by f.id order by f.date)))  
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, log_factor order by date) as seqnum
      from factor_table f
     ) f;
```

Comment: Window functions cannot operate over `distinct`

Comment: @user1742188 . . . Of course; that is easily fixed.